# Reactjs Table Component

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

I've been using Fixed Data Table and i want to show/hide rows on row click. I couldn't find anything related to show/hide or sub table in react fixed data table. Is there any way to achieve this or any other table component which will help me achieve this.

Comment: You could simply bind an onclick function to manipulate input rows upon rowclick but if you want try others, check out [Griddle React](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle).

Comment: Thanks.. But using onclick i can't show/hide rows as i need to recalculate other table rows height to inject the row in between... As far as Griddle is concerned it's still in alfa stage i guess